# Unindenting code snippets

Tags: emacs, tabs

There are times that I have a code snippet that I want to post on a defect tracker, wiki, forum, etc.   but it's deeply indented in the code.  I usually have to highlight the code snippet, hit <shift>-<tab> until the indents aren't so bad, then copy/paste and then revert the code.  It gets somewhat painful.

Is there a tool that can remove the tabs in front of the each line?  Note that I don't want to remove all tabs from all lines, just same preceding number of tabs from each line.  I'm thinking some function of Emacs could do this.

Here's an extreme example:

Before:

```
                            //This is usually some method in an anonymous inner class' anonymous inner class.
                            @Override
                            public void method(){
                                doSomething();
                            }
```

After:

```
//This is usually some method in an anonymous inner class' anonymous inner class.
@Override
public void method(){
    doSomething();
}
```

Notice how doSomething() still has a single tab in front of it.

Comment: @Roger:  Thanks for the comment.  I re-worded the question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Rectangle selection is my preferred way of doing this.

Put yourself at the beginning of the first line, <kbd>C-space</kbd>, go to the last line, and the end of the indentation you want to remove and <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> (rectangular kill). That does it.

Comment: I do not like this method, since whitespace is the problem you should only remove whitespace, this method removes all characters in the region.

Comment: This is the way I've always done it as well. But I'm liking the indent-rigidly solution @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060442/unindenting-code-snippets/2060803#2060803

Comment: I had to read it a couple of times to understand "go to the last line and the end of indentation".  Now rectangular kill makes sense.  If only there were an emacs function that could automatically kill the rectangle, copy the code to clipboard, then undo the kill.

Answer (score 13):

The actual method to do this in Emacs is with this key combination.

First select the section you want to remove the tabs from.

You could select the entire buffer:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>

Or, if you just want a region simply set the mark <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> where you want to begin and then navigate to where you want to end.

Then remove whitespace, for 10 whitespace characters do this:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Since this is quite big, I'll break it down for you.

1) First we give the negative-argument command:

(negative-argument ARG)

kbd shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

2) Next supply the numerical argument, in this case the number 10:

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

3) Then we call the indent-rigidly command

(indent-rigidly START END ARG)

kbd shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>

So what we are doing is giving the argument of -10 to the command to indent-rigidly and the result is that 10 whitespace characters will be removed from the beginning of each line which we have selected, in this case we have the entire document selected (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>), so 10 lines of whitespace will be removed from the beginning of every line of the entire document.

If a particular line has less than 10 whitespace it will only remove as many whitespace as possible, if there are more than 10 whitespace then some may be left over after it is finished.

In your example it looks like you have about 30 leading whitespace, so this should do the trick:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Try a larger number if you want to remove more.

Answer (score 8):

If you have your emacs c-style settings correct, then simply highlighting the snippet and pressing `C-M-\` will indent it properly (if you're in c++-mode).

Comment: Just wanted to note that this method probably is useful for any language emacs detects (worked for me with Javascript). This seems like the best answer to me, and the closet to Sublime's Ctrl-[, which I find convenient too.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer I think . . to UN-indent selected region by 4:

```
C-u -4 C-x TAB
```

That is the simple region indent command with negative argument.
e.g this indents region by one:

```
C-x TAB
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html

Answer (score 1):

The method I use in Kedit (which has the capability of doing column editing) is to mark the first character of the first column and row with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>, position my cursor to the last row and character that I want to remove, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> again and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>. It's Gone and still has all of the indenting beyond the removed columns.
In SQL Server it's easier, mark the block and press shift-tab until the code is where I want it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly how many tabs prefix each line (as you state), you could use a simple `query-replace-regex` to replace `"^\t\t\t...\t"` with `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to remove the leading whitespace.

In Emacs:

```
C-M-%^<TAB><TAB><TAB><ENTER><ENTER>!
```

In Vim:

```
:%s/^\t\t\t//g
```

Comment: This only removes the first 3 tabs on each line.  So a 4th or 5th indent would become a 1st or 2nd.  The '^' character denotes "start-of-line".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, unless you are seriously suggesting that he should copy the text from emacs, paste into vim, modify, and copy that to paste elsewhere, and that doesn't seem like a useful answer.  Also requires to count the number of unindents, and surely there's a better way.

Comment: I didn't notice the 'emacs' tag, hence the solution in vim.  Adding an emacs variant.

Comment: @Roger - Yep Bahbar posted an elegant solution.  Generally I don't mind counting, but in emacs his way is definitely better.

Answer (score -3):

In vi, it's just `<<` to left shift by one indent width, so to unindent 10 lines, you would do `10<<`.